# What does the phrase "Lady-Macbethed" mean?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, shakespeare

> Colonel Hampton snorted contemptuously. Senile dementia! Well, he must
>   have been senile and demented, to bring this pair of snakes into his
>   home, because he felt an obligation to his dead brother's memory. And
>   he'd willed "Greyrock," and his money, and everything, to Stephen.
>   Only Myra couldn't wait till he died; she'd Lady-Macbethed her husband
>   into this insanity accusation.

The above text is taken from the novel Dearest, by Henry Beam Piper. What does the phrase "Lady-Macbethed" means? Is it old usage, or do we also use this phrase in modern times?

Comment: H. Beam Piper's writing is not what I'd call antiquated, just brilliant (and not so prevalent a lot of more recent sf.)

Comment: I think this is Too Localised. Lady Macbeth's role in ["The Scottish Play"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scottish_Play) isn't part of *English **Language*** - it's just a piece of shared *cultural* knowledge among (reasonably) well-read Anglophones. But even someone who's never heard of Lady Macbeth can easily look it up on somewhere like Wikipedia; ELU isn't the place to address such cultural references. So it's also General Reference, or Off Topic Lit Crit, if you want to look at it that way.

Comment: Adding to what FumbleFingers says, I find it rather telling that the question is *tagged* "shakespeare", by the OP himself. With that in mind, I am not seeing much of a question here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

She acted like Lady Macbeth did to Macbeth in Shakespeare's "Macbeth", goading and brow-beating him into a course of action he might otherwise have rejected as immoral, or not even considered.

> Is it old usage, or do we also use this phrase in modern times?

Neither; the author is taking the well-known character, and turning her name into a verb to represent her actions in the play, and generalise it to similar actions by others. It's not a general usage.

Comment: There are other examples, too. From the Bible: _he was a Judas_ (traitor), _he was a Jonathon_ (close friend), _he was a Jonah_ (bringer of bad luck). A more recent use, with a name-turned-verb: _they decided to [bork](http://books.google.com/books?id=35dZpfMmxqsC&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=%22bork+the+nominee%22&source=bl&ots=k9uVSGteL8&sig=UFwC-gs4thVMg9zyq_hSJb5nIsU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yaEjUdyYE4Oo2gXK2YHYCw&ved=0CFwQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22bork%20the%20nominee%22&f=false) the nominee_ (attempt to derail the nomination).

Comment: @J.R. though as a non-American who moves in techie circles I'm more familiar with *bork* meaning "broken" (a joke; so broken even the spelling is broken). There are indeed certainly plenty in frequent use from the Bible (*Martha* and *Methuselah* come to mind), others from Shakespeare (*Romeo*, *Shylock*) and other myths and stories. I think here though we've a case not of such uses becoming common meanings, but of being coined as needed by an author.

Comment: Should we boycott such devices?

Comment: One word: MacGyver'd

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You've got a possible folk-etymology in there with *device*, though *boycott* is one of the more easily demonstrable cases. I recently saw a Facebook group that misspelled *boycott* three different ways and not once got it correct, which would have been a forgiveable enough mistake had their protest not been over the portray of something in 19th C Connacht!

Comment: Ah - beyond the Pale (and in the corridor of uncertainty).

Comment: In the U.S., we sometimes use _Benedict Arnold_ to indicate someone is a traitor. I wonder if in the U.K. it refers to someone who is loyal unto death.

Comment: @J.R. He's better known as a point of American modern cultural reference than otherwise. It's quite interesting that Quisling fulfills the same rôle in much of Europe, even where the history of the occupation of Norway is one of the least well-explored aspects of WWII history. Me, I'd like to use Pearse to mean "suicide mystic foolishly put in charge of a military action", but some consider that unpatriotic.

Comment: This is similar in meaning to the expression "to pull a [Name]," referring to act like that person in a signature way or "[I need] to channel my inner [H. Beam Piper] and get a small fuzzy," or I  "She really pulled a Lady Macbeth on that one."

Comment: The not-now-so-contentious assertion that one 'may verb any noun' could give rise to a rash of new usages from nounal eponyms: to bakelite, Bailey bridge, Belisha beacon, blondel ... There are a few eponyms or derivatives that are verbs already: asphalt, bowdlerise, boycott, cannibalise, degauss, diddle, grangerise, guillotine, hoover, hypnotise, lynch, mentor, mesmerise, pander, panic, slave, tarmac and vandalise.